# Get average of cells conditionally in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, average

I have a table in Excel with 2 columns. Column A (Owner) has a list of names. Column B (Duration) has a list of numbers. I need to get the average of numbers for each of the owner. So for James it would be (4 + 5 + 18) / 3. I know how to get the average in Excel but I don't know how to conditional say:
 Use the value in Column B if value in A = "James"

```
A         B
---------------
Owner  Duration
James  4
Dan    67
Ger    3
James  5
Ger    75
James  18
```

Answer (score 3):

The `AVERAGEIF` function will allow you to do this.

```
=AVERAGEIF(A2:A7,"James",B2:B7)
```

- The first argument is the range which will be subject to the criteria
- The second argument is the criteria.
- The third argument is the range (corresponding to the first range) with values to be averaged.

There is also a SUMIF, COUNTIF, and others.

Comment: But this will only do it for a single name not for all names in the list

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do this in a pivot table.

- Select all your data.
- Go to Insert >> pivot table >> click ok
- Select both columns (COLA, COLB) from the list of fields
        available on the right.
- By default COLB will go under VALUES.
        Click on the arrow that says Sum of COLB >> click on value field
        settings >> Select Average function instead of sum.
  Check this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-report-d09e4d07-8cd6-4b60-afad-8fb67418800f?CorrelationId=78b545a8-649b-400a-9941-a23ef409c95b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#_Toc263767342 for more info on pivot tables